# how to layer multiple regression lines without repeating code?

Tags: vega-lite

I'm using Vega Lite to chart the times at which I eat my meals, and want a regression (loess) line showing the general time for each. By default, a regression uses the entire dataset and only shows one line; I want three lines, one for each meal (stored in the field `extra_data.content`).

I've achieved what I want to do my repeating the loess layer three times ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrH7e.png)) but am trying to find a solution in which the same layer is written once and repeats itself three times.

**Edit after solving!** Thanks very much to @jakevdp for the answer! Here is my working code; note that there is both a `groupby` on the loess and a `color` channel.

```json
        {
            "mark": "line",
            "transform": [
                {
                    "loess": "hm",
                    "on": "ymd",
                    "groupby": ["extra_data.content"]
                }
            ],
            "encoding": {
                "x": {
                    "field": "ymd",
                    "type": "temporal"
                },
                "y": {
                    "field": "hm",
                    "type": "temporal"
                },
                "color": {
                    "field": "extra_data.content",
                    "type": "nominal"
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `groupby` argument of the loess transform, along with a color encoding. It might look something like this:

```json
{
  "mark": "line",
  "transform": [
    {
      "loess": "hm",
      "on": "ymd",
      "groupby": ["extradata.content"]
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "ymd",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "hm",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "extradata.content",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I use this exact code, the chart rendered (Vega Viewer) is completely blank. Removing the `grouby` section allows the graph to be rendered, but of course there's only a single loess line based on the entire dataset. I will experiment with another Vega viewer, and look into transforms. Please let me know if you have another idea!

Comment: Your code had `extradata` instead of `extra_data`. Once I fixed this, the chart is rendering exactly how I want. I'll edit my OP with the working code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked! Sorry for the typo: you didn't provide any example data so I wasn't able to actually run the code in my answer. In the future including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help prevent these kinds of typos.